# How do I solve the integral $\int\frac{1-\sqrt{2x+3}}{1+\sqrt{2x+3}}dx$ with help substitution?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

How do I solve the integral $$\int\frac{1-\sqrt{2x+3}}{1+\sqrt{2x+3}}dx$$ with help substitution?

For example, if I set $t=\sqrt{2x+3}$, would that be a possible option? And if so, how would I go about it? Appreciate any hints and methods, since I'm new to this topic.

Comment: is your integral correct? check it again

Comment: No, you're right. Changed the denominator to $1+\sqrt{2x+3}$ now. Sorry

Comment: "if I set $t=\sqrt{2x+3}$, would that be a possible option?" Indeed! But did you try it? Or what is the problem when you try to?

Comment: At first glance it looks like an excellent candidate for multiplication by $1={1-\sqrt{2x+3}\over 1-\sqrt{2x+3}}={1+\sqrt{2x+3}\over 1+\sqrt{2x+3}}$...

Comment: @abiessu At second glance, not so much...

Comment: @Did: the $1-\dots$ form, I agree, but the $1+\dots$ form seems to work out okay...

Comment: @abiessu You mean,  $$\int\frac{1-\sqrt{2x+3}}{1+\sqrt{2x+3}}dx=\int\frac{1-\sqrt{2x+3}}{1+\sqrt{2x+3}}\frac{1+\sqrt{2x+3}}{1+\sqrt{2x+3}}dx=\ldots\ ?$$ Hmmm, I might be missing something but this seems to lead to a nightmare.

Comment: @Did: no, you're right, it doesn't work out nicely.  The only redeeming quality of the $1-\dots$ form was that the numerator could be separated nicely with a linear denominator, which is why I brought up the suggestion, but then I noticed the added zero in the denominator and realized that the $1+\dots$ form wouldn't have that... Oh well.  It was a nice thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $ t = \sqrt{2x+3} $ is a good option.

${ t = \sqrt{2x+3} \Rightarrow t^2 = 2x+3 \Rightarrow x = {t^2-3\over2} \\  dx = t dt \\ 
\int{(1-t)t\over1+t}dt = - \int{{t^2-t}\over{t+1}}dt = -\int(t-2) dt - 2\int{dt\over t+1}}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! May I ask why $\partial x = t\partial t$ and not just $\partial t$? Also, why is the numerator $(1-t)t$ and not just $1-t$. Appreciate the help!

Comment: You need to learn how to do substitution in integral.  How to complute the relation between $dx$ and $dt$, knowing the relation between $x$ and $t$.